# Ionic 3 Upgrade to Ionic 4: Template parse errors Conflicting components

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Trying to take an ionic 3 project and upgrade it to ionic 4. I have all the packages upgraded and everything builds but on serve I'm getting conflicting component template parse errors.

I feel like this is a bit of a red-herring because if I remove the offending code, it throws the parse error on another component. I'm looking for some help to figure out what could be causing this issue.

**Error**:

```html
Error: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: Content,IonContent ("}" description="{{ city }}, {{ state.abbreviation }}"></app-page-header>
</ion-col>
[ERROR ->]<ion-content class="dark">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
"): ng:///MyPageModule/MyPage.html@3:0
```

**my.page.html**

```html
<ion-col no-padding>
  <app-page-header title="{{ name }}" description="{{ city }}, {{ state.abbreviation }}"></app-page-header>
</ion-col>
<ion-content class="dark">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
    .... redacted ...
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**my.page.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, LoadingController, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DataService } from './../../app/data.service';
import { UserService } from './../../app/user.service';
import { GlobalVars } from './../../app/globalvars';

@IonicPage({
  name: 'my',
  segment: 'my/:id'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.page.scss'],
})

export class MyPage implements OnInit {};

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private userService: UserService, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform: Platform, public globalVars: GlobalVars) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id:number = +this.navParams.get('id');
    if(id) {
      this.getAsdf(id).then(
        res => {
           this.loadAllReleases(id);
        },
        err => {
            
        }
      );
      sessionStorage.setItem("newRoot","brewery");
      sessionStorage.setItem("newRootId", id.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  <ion-menu side="left" type="overlay" [content]="mycontent" col-lg-5 col-12 no-padding>
      <ion-content>
          <button class="menu-close" ion-button icon-only menuClose detail-none>
              <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <img class="logo" src="./../../assets/imgs/logo.png" float-left />
          <ion-list no-lines>
              <button ion-item menuClose (click)="navTo('releases')">
                  Releases
              </button>
              <button ion-item menuClose (click)="navTo('cart')">
                  Cart
              </button>
          </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-nav #mycontent [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
  <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}"></span>
  <toaster-container [toasterconfig]="toasterConfig"></toaster-container>
</ion-app>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AuthModule } from './auth.module';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ToasterConfig } from 'angular2-toaster';
import { GlobalVars } from './../app/globalvars';
import { NavController, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { InAppBrowserService } from './in-app-browser.service';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

let jQuery: any;
var el: JQuery;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  private unsubscribe$ = new ReplaySubject();
  @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
  rootPage: any = 'welcome';
  mobilePlatform: boolean;
  toasterConfig: ToasterConfig = new ToasterConfig({
    positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
    showCloseButton: true,
    timeout: 5000,      
    animation: 'fade'    
  });

  constructor(notificationService: NotificationService, 
              public platform: Platform, 
              statusBar: StatusBar, 
              splashScreen: SplashScreen,
              private authModule: AuthModule, 
              private globalVars: GlobalVars,
              public app: App, 
              private iabService: InAppBrowserService,
              private dataService: DataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    //REDACTED...
    
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
      console.log('error trapped', event);
    });
  }
  
  login() {
    // Check to see if we're on a mobile (aka codova) platform
    if(this.platform.is("cordova")){

      //REDACTED
    }
    else {
      //REDACTED
    }    
  }

  logout() {
    this.authModule.logOut();
  }

  admin() {
    window.location.href = Environment.adminUri;
  }

  navTo(route: string) {
    this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(route);
  }

  handleOneSignalUser(){
    this.dataService.handleOneSignalUser();
  }
}
```

Comment: You have old Ionic 3 import here: import { IonicPage, LoadingController, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular'; in your page. You should only use new imports from Ionic 4 now (from '@ionic/angular';)

Answer (score 0):

here is your Error

```
  <app-page-header title="{{ name }}" description="{{ city }}, {{ state.abbreviation }}"></app-page-header>
```

do you have those data

EG:

```
name
city
state.abbreviation
```

Comment: Yes, because even if I remove that component the parse error persists... which is why I'm thinking it's a red herring

Comment: Same template error:
Error: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: Content,IonContent ("
  
</ion-col>
[ERROR ->]<ion-content class="dark">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a combination of still importing ionic 3 things and not properly importing all the components in a shared module in all the necessary modules it was being used.